# Argument Type (typescript)

Tags: typescript

Como debo pasar los datos a la función check

**user.ts**

```
import { Fields } from './fields';
import { dataUser } from './interface';
import { validate } from "class-validator";

export class User  {

    check(data:dataUser){

        let user= new Fields();
        user.name=data.name;
        user.lastname=data.lastname;
        user.document=data.document;
        user.gender=data.gender;
        user.email=data.email;
        user.password=data.password;
        user.terms=data.terms;
        user.privacy=data.privacy;
        user.idDocumentType=data.idDocumentType;
        user.idCity=data.idCity;

        validate(user).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });

    }

}
```

**interface.ts**

```
export interface dataUser{
    name: string,
    lastname: string,
    document: string,
    gender: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    terms: string,
    privacy: string,
    idDocumentType: number,
    idCity: number,

}
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import { User } from './user/user'
import { dataUser } from './user/interface';
const user:User = new User();

$(function() {
    $("#store-user-send").click(function(){

        let dataUsers: dataUser[] =[];
        dataUsers.push({
            name:String( $("#name").val() ),
            lastname:String( $("#lastname").val() ),
            document:String( $("#document").val() ),
            gender:String( $("#gender").val() ),
            email:String( $("#email").val() ),
            password:String( $("#password").val() ),
            terms:String( $("#terms").val() ),
            privacy:String( $("#privacy").val() ),
            idDocumentType:1,
            idCity:1,
        });
        user.check(dataUsers[0]);

    });
});
```

Comment: Podrias por favor quitar las imagenes y poner el codigo real en la pregunta? las imagenes son dificiles de ver y no permiten copiarlo para hacer pruebas. mira por favro [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observando las imagenes se puede ver que el metodo Check de la clase User recibe como parámetro un objeto dataUser, pero tú en el fichero app.ts en la línea 22

```
user.check(dataUsers);
```

Siendo dataUsers un array de la clase dataUser por lo que te da ese error.
Observando como rellenas el array no me queda clara que quieres hacer exactamente, pero si quieres pasar el primer elemento tendrías que hacer

```
user.check(dataUsers[0]);
```

De esta forma te queda mejor el código, ya que el array no lo necesitas.

```
    let dataUser: dataUser = {
        name:String( $("#name").val() ),
        lastname:String( $("#lastname").val() ),
        document:String( $("#document").val() ),
        gender:String( $("#gender").val() ),
        email:String( $("#email").val() ),
        password:String( $("#password").val() ),
        terms:String( $("#terms").val() ),
        privacy:String( $("#privacy").val() ),
        idDocumentType:1,
        idCity:1,
    };
user.check(dataUser);
```

Comment: El arreglo lo voy a rellenar con datos de un formulario, Gracias ya así me sirvió pero si ahí una forma mas optima me gustaría saberla gracias.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es si te hace falta ese array, ya que si lo vas a rellenar de un formulario creo que simplemente tendrías que crear el objeto dataUser y rellenarlo.

Comment: Listo bro gracias ya edite así como dices gracias

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que tu código quede más limpio, ya que el arreglo no te hace falta.

Comment: Aa de una mucho mejor gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema debe ser que le estás pasando un arreglo de objetos `dataUser`, pero el `check` está **recibiendo** solo un objeto `dataUser`. 
En el error dice que `dataUser[]` no es asignable a `dataUser`, un arreglo no se puede asignar a un objeto. En todo caso debes sacar un elemento del array (arreglo) y asignárselo a la función `check`